# what is "Unknown(0x)" error when swapping tokens in web3.js?

Tags: swap, web3js

I'm swapping tokens using web3.js sometimes it succeeds and sometimes it fails, but when it fails I get this error in my console:

```
VM Exception while processing transaction: revert callBytes failed: Unknown(0x)
```

and I believe it is the same as the error below from etherscan:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w2cH.png)

can someone please tell me what is this error and how to solve it?

thank you for your time.

Comment: I guess I found why this issue accrued, it is because the transaction data letters was + 14,000 letter, but the transaction data should work I got it from a defi protocol, how to fix this problem, which is sending a transaction with +14,000 letters without getting this error? thanx

Comment: I removed the `DEX` tag as it was totally wrong on your question: It is for Android Java dex code. Please read the tag description before using it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.